# Word for a person who talks without content

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for a person who reiterates without adding any new content? (This person is not necessarily talkative per se.) Example of a conversation by such a person would be:

> "You know if we do this *xyz*, it will be good. No one has done *xyz* so it is going to be great if we finish *xyz*, I don't think anyone has done this.  By summer if this is done then we can send *xyz*, of course we have to do it before and it's gonna be great and we have to keep doing *xyz* unless someone will do it, but no one has done it yet, it is going to be great if we do *xyz*."

It is not overzeal; it is just my example which came out to be like this.

Comment: Two words come into my mind, rain man and women ;)

Comment: related: [Speaking for the sake of saying something](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59867/speaking-for-the-sake-of-saying-something); and [Is there a word for a person who gives out too many extraneous details?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15940/is-there-a-word-for-a-person-who-gives-out-too-many-extraneous-details)

Comment: +1 for "rain man". -10 for "women"... that's just offensive. Especially since it's known that [men talk more than women,](http://www.livescience.com/7420-men-talk-women.html) and interrupt more than women.  </grumble>, now let's get back to word definitions.

Comment: also related: [What is the name of the tactic that politicians use to bury people with torrent of words?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160126/what-is-the-name-of-the-tactic-that-politicians-use-to-bury-people-with-torrent) and my favourite but used in its BrEng sense “waffle” — ["the meaning of ‘waffle’ most familiar to me is to talk or write at great length without actually saying very much"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42718/meaning-of-whiffling-and-waffling/42728#42728)

Comment: Opposite of straight talk is so big that it will surely encompass this. But this is more specialized. But probably I am searching in vain, so I will accept that after waiting for a few days for other views.

Comment: [***Scotsmen***](http://www.ourcivilisation.com/smartboard/shop/lamb/nt/002.htm) ;)

Comment: Politician. :-|

Comment: The phrasing of your question suggests you're looking for an adjective, but if your purpose is search, verbs would do just as well: babbling, digressing, reiterating, are terms that (while they do not necessarily _describe_ the behavior you are after), are likely to come up. I'm sure others can come up with much more apt terms, if you only make it clear that verbs are relevant.

Comment: You're not describing an *aphasic*, are you? Someone with a problem like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receptive_aphasia)?

Comment: @mukhujje Welcome to the ELU :-). It helps to be as precise as possible in the original question. To get the answer you desire, it would be best if you edited your post to include the remark that you are looking for a medical term. You can point out that it is an edit, so that the already provided answers don't seem nonsensical, since many people tried very hard to give you an answer.

Answer (score 14):

**Gasbag** (*slang*) - A person whose talks are devoid of content, i.e., gaseous.

[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gasbag) - One given to empty or boastful talk.

Comment: Gasbag is so far the best match, but as I am looking for the medical condition through a google search with the word I don't think this one will be of much help.

Comment: Why does that remind me of Super Mario and the P-balloons?

Comment: @mukhujje Talking a lot without saying anything is not a medical condition. A very similar term, which was the first thought that came into my mind upon reading the question title, is ***windbag***, which strikes me as slightly less offensive than _gasbag_.

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if it's what you're after, but you could try "[rambler](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rambler)".

> **[ramble](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ramble)**
>
> - to talk or write in an aimless way.
> - (of speech, writing) to lack organisation.

Comment: Not to be confused with a [rambler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramblers) :-)

Comment: @user77639 Which is lacking organisation (hence, the second meaning).

Answer (score 7):

I would offer [*blatherskate*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blatherskite#English) or *blatherskite* :

> A voluble purveyor of nonsense; a blusterer.
>
> Nonsense or blather; empty talk.

Answer (score 7):

As far as a diagnostic search term, *logorrhea* may be most appropriate. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logorrhea_%28psychology%29):

> a communication disorder, expressed by excessive wordiness with minor
>   or sometimes incoherent talkativeness.

A related search term could be *aphasia* or *aphasic*, which refers to a general class of language disorders.

---

As for precise usage, the verb that comes to mind is *bloviate*. From Merriam-Webster:

> to speak or write verbosely and windily

Comment: @mukhujje commented that they wanted a medical condition. This fits.

Answer (score 5):

**Blatherer**

blather at [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blather):

> to talk foolishly at length —often used with on : Old Norse blathra; akin to Middle High German blōdern to chatter
>   First Known Use: 1524

Blatherer at [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/blatherer):

> someone who blathers

Answer (score 4):

**Bloviator**, from

> **bloviate**: talk at length, especially in an inflated or empty way.

[source](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/bloviate)

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-). Can you please provide a reference for the definition as suggested on the [help centre](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) page? This way the answer would be even more helpful to the OP and future users of the website. You can always edit your own posts, regardless of your reputation.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose such a person might be called a **pleonast**.

From [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pleonast)

> *Pleonast*:
>   One who is addicted to pleonasm, or redundancy in speech or writing.

Answer (score 2):

If you want something colorful, for someone who *does* talk a lot, go with *chatterbox*. For someone who just uses a lot of words to say what they're saying, how about [*long-winded.*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/long-winded)

Comment: Thanks alexis, I understand that you (the users of this stackexchange ) are probably writers so you are trying to find the best fit in a writer sort of way, but I need to describe this to google search who will search through a pile of psychiatrist sites to give me my answer. So long-winded even though describes best the speech of this person will not be of much help.

Comment: Yeah, Alexis, the best remedy for having nothing to say is to say it a lot.

Comment: @mukhujje, if you're looking for a word suited to a particular language style (formal/informal, medical jargon etc.), you should edit your answer and add this information. If you want to know how a _psychologist_ would characterize a patient who talks around an issue, say so. (And why exactly is "long-winded" unsuited for googling?)

Answer (score 2):

**[Redundant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/redundant)**: 
characterized by verbosity or unnecessary repetition in expressing ideas.

Comment: Hi Giorgio, that's a great word, and welcome to ELU!  Can you provide a link to where you found that definition?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative option would be a **[duck / duckspeaker](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duckspeak)** (coined by George Orwell in 1984):

> Thoughtless or formulaic speech.

Answer (score 2):

[long-winded](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/long-winded)

> *adjective*
>
> 1. talking or writing at tedious length: *"**long-winded** after-dinner speakers."*
> 2. continued to a tedious length in speech or writing: *"another of his **long-winded** election speeches."*

Answer (score 1):

*Rambler* is good for someone who goes on and on, but at a normal pace and without indications of anxiety.

I get the feeling that the speaker in the example is nervous—that they're going on and on because they don't think they've been clear, or that their audience needs more convincing, or that they just can't relax (too much coffee?). I'd call such a person a *compulsive talker*, or, in a less-kind way, a *babbler*.

Comment: Could be compulsive talker, I looked at the wiki page it sounds similar. And I got another word from the same page "talkaholic" :) But definitely not too much coffee.

Answer (score 1):

Perseverator, or one who perseverates, which means to repeat something insistently or redundantly.
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/perseverate?s=ts

Answer (score 0):

Colourful and not for polite use, a favourite of mine is 'Gobshite'.

[Collins definition](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gobshite)

Comment: A gobshite is just an idiot. It’s nothing to do with the person’s level of longwindedness.

Answer (score 0):

A Whiffler

A whiffler is someone who 'whiffles on' - talks without saying very much.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whiffler

Answer (score 0):

**Chatterbox** : one who engages in much idle talk.

Besides 'Rambler' and 'Blatherer' this also comes to my mind!

[Merriam Webster - Chatterbox](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chatterbox)