# Words describing people that cannot stop talking

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

What words can be used to describe someone who likes to talk continuously and unstoppably?

Would that be a gabber? What else could you call them?

How do these words relate to the way the person is feeling while they are talking?

Comment: Grabber? Where did you find that word?

Comment: See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/242760/word-for-a-person-who-talks-without-content/242770

Comment: You might mean ***gabber*** not *grabber*.  Or they might be a *motor-mouth*

Comment: Do you care if the word has a negative or a positive connotation?

Comment: There is more to connotation to words, I am suggesting there actually may be a hidden logic behind it. Just an idea.

Answer (score 8):

> [**chatterbox**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/chatterbox) (slang) - A person who talks at length about trivial matters.
>
> [**windbag**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/windbag) (slang) - an exhaustively talkative person; person who talks too much
>
> [**garrulous**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/garrulousness) -  tending to talk a lot; very talkative

Comment: +1 I like your first three. I don’t like *circumlocutory* as well here.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't going to add it, seeing how it has a slightly different meaning than just "talkative".  I should remove it as it pertains more to writing than speech.

Answer (score 4):

***[Logorrheic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/logorrheic)***  (adj.):

> pertaining to the over use of words or excessive talkativeness.

Collins Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

***talkaholic***

From **Wiktionary**:

> **[talkaholic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/talkaholic)**: An incessant talker.
>
> "Are you a Talkaholic?"
>
> If you are a Talkaholic, you throw out words as you would darts to
>   keep people away from you.
>
> No words were spoken for a long time. This was plainly killing Kerra
>   who was a talk-aholic.
>
> Synonyms: motormouth
>
> Related terms: talkaholism
>
> **[incessant](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/incessant)**‎(comparative more incessant, superlative most incessant):
>
> Without pause or stop; not ending, especially to the point of
>   annoyance.
>
> The dog's incessant barking kept the girl awake all night.
>
> **[talker](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/talker)**‎(plural talkers):
>
> A person who talks, especially one who gives a speech, or is
>   loquacious or garrulous.
>
> What this country needs is a smooth talker.
>
> That guy's a real talker.
>
> **[loquacious](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loquacious)** ‎(comparative more loquacious, superlative most loquacious):
>
> Talkative or chatty, especially of persons given to excess
>   conversation.
>
> **[garrulous](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/garrulous)** ‎(comparative more garrulous, superlative most garrulous):
>
> Excessively or tiresomely talkative.

Answer (score 0):

[**Compulsive talking**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compulsive_talking)

> Compulsive talking (also known as **talkaholism**) goes beyond the bounds of what is considered to be a socially acceptable amount of talking.

**[Chunter](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/chunter#chunter__1)**

> to talk for a long time about something that other people do not find interesting.

Comment: So here we have it, another psychiatric disorder. Just great.

Comment: Anyways, I am not satisfied with this list of answers. But thanks.

Comment: Important to know that exactly the word you put in bold has a marker on wiki which pretty much doubts its existence.